# GUI blocked during Canvas update - how to optimize this?

Tags: performance, canvas, javafx-2

I am drawing about 12.000 objects to a JavaFX 2.2 Canvas. The GUI blocks for around 2 seconds, while measuring the execution time of my code claims less than half a second execution time for my code.

So I am wondering how the measured execution time of my code can be so far shorter than the time the GUI is blocked - I guess there's some kind of buffering on the Canvas, so things are first written to the buffer and processed later? So after ~0.5 seconds, everything I drew to the Canvas was only written to the buffer?

Assuming everything is buffered first leads to my next question: Isn't the drawing of the things in the buffer always done on the UI-Thread, so I can't optimize the timespan where the GUI is blocked through to drawing things from the buffer? Even if I would draw to the Canvas from the Application thread, when the buffer is still processed on the UI thread, then I won't get rid of this 1,5 seconds blocking of the GUI?

Thanks for any hint!

**Update: Pseudocode:**

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

// Using GraphicsContext, draw ~ 12.000 arc parts (GraphicsContext.drawArc method)
// to a Canvas

long end = System.nanoTime();
double elapsedTime = (end-start)/1000000000.0; //in seconds
System.out.println("elapsed time: " + elapsedTime); // something around 0.5, however the GUI hangs for around 2 seconds - where do the additional 1.5 seconds come from?
```

I am doing everything on the application thread, so I understand that the GUI hangs for the 0.5 seconds during which I am adding stuff to the Canvas. However I can't understand, why the GUI hangs for ~2 seconds, when my drawing to the Canvas finished after 0.5 seconds?

Comment: I don't know, what to comment by subject, but I can suggest to file an RFE, or a bug in JavaFX jira, about the fact, that UI is blocked. Developers, possibly, will investigate, and may be, will fix it, or will say, what you can do. You will have to attach a test case. (possibly, your code). Provide a link here, if you will do it. But previously, try to look at this : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24274

Comment: BTW, which version of JFX you use?

Comment: I am using the version included in Java 7 U13. I will add some sample pseudo code alter, as I don't know much about all those threading stuff and I am not sure if it's maybe not my fault ;-) Currently reading up a little bit on this topic.

Comment: When you work, I can also try JDK 8, with JFX 8, from here http://jdk8.java.net/download.html. Possibly, it works better. If not your fault, and it hangs UI, it could be a bug (adding items to control hangs UI - that is a bug, at least). So, let look at your code.

Comment: BTW, if you don't know about threading.. At least, try to look at javafx.concurrent package. It contains some primitives for concurrent work in javafx. If you have an operation which takes 0.5 second to prepare data, you will need to move it in a separate thread, not to hang a UI.

Comment: I had a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm Was quite helpful. My 0.5 second operation actually already draws to the Canvas, so I need GUI access. Anyway, the main thing I am wondering about is that the GUI is blocked for 2 seconds and not only 0.5 seconds. Is it possible that this is due to some buffering before something is actually really drawn on the Canvas?

Comment: I see, that you do nothing except of arc rendering.. So, it looks like a bug..

Comment: Stefan, could you provide a link on a code, or extend an existing code snippet from issue description (I'll try to file an issue) with arc creation code? If you will not file it by yourself.

Comment: I'll try to create a reduced example for that case that I can share, might take some time though, but probably during this day :-)

Comment: example will take longer, but it's not forgotten!